# Can or can't questions be migrated after 60 days?

Tags: support, flags, migration

I came across this relatively old question from 2010 today, [Critique my Lisp, please](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3896015/1281433).  I know that older questions often don't meet today's standards, and that sometimes they're locked, and preserved for historical significance. (E.g., see the discussions in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114908).  I'd normally just let this question be, except that it's an *ideal* fit for Code Review, so I flagged with the reason:

> Migrate to Code Review. This is an old "critique my code" question
>   that might have been on-topic when it was posted, but is off-topic
>   now. It's an ideal fit for Code Review though. It should either be
>   migrated, or historically locked.

That flag got declined with the response

> declined - questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated

I'm not too worried about that;  it's not a big deal whether this one gets migrated or not.  However, it doesn't seem true that questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated.  I was alerted that [Should "Professionals and enthusiasts" be qualified in the help center?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258081/1281433), which was asked October 21, 2013, which is over six months ago, was migrated yesterday (June 3, 2014).

I don't mind the declined flag, but what's the story here on whether questions can be migrated after 60 days.  The decline reason says they can't, but personal experience indicates that they can.

Comment: That's a special case because it was from Meta to meta SO, and done by an SE employee

Comment: @random So it's not that they *cannot* be migrated, but rather *will not* be migrated.  I have no problem with that, if that's the policy, it's just not clear from the text.

Comment: No, it's that they *cannot* be migrated.  The software specifically prevents migrations that are over 60 days old, unless someone from SE overrides the restriction.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: It seems rather to be a case of who can, and who not. Involving SE employees for moderation actions seems a bit too much

Comment: @RobertHarvey random *did* mention "employee".  If an employee had a way to do it (and I'll even qualify as "if an employee had a convenient user interface to do it, not by editing the database, etc.") it's clear that questions can be migrated.  I think PlasmaHH is on the right track;  it's that [normal] moderators can't migrate after 60 days.  Since they'd be doing most of the migrating, it's not a big deal that the message doesn't reveal all the possible things that can happen. It was just an incongruity that I noticed between yesterday and today.

Comment: As a matter of general principle, SE employees do not get involved in the day-to-day operations of the sites at that level.  The Meta split was an administrative action, not a community one.

Comment: More intresting to know would be a reason. Is this something technical, or has "social" aspects?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: A reason for what?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That makes perfect sense, and I wouldn't expect it to be otherwise.  Again, it was just a matter of "can't be migrated? but wait, wasn't this one ...?"  There's no mention in the migrated one that it wasn't migrated in the normal fashion.  I'm not complaining about this, but just wanted to understand what was happening.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The 60 days. I can't think of a reason quite now for why the community would want to prevent this for questions older than 60 days.

Comment: @PlasmaHH See [this old mSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'd suggest reading the MSE post I linked to in my answer.  It's messy, very messy.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Well if you really want to be technical, then anything *can* be done. The SE team has access to the database, and can do pretty much anything they wanted if they really wanted to. They *can* cause a mysterious drop of 200,000 in Jon Skeet's reputation, but that won't happen.

Comment: @animuson :) And that's why I said "(and I'll even qualify as "if an employee had a convenient user interface to do it, not by editing the database, etc.")".  Oy, it's like this is a site full of programmers sometimes.

Comment: It's really a shame that even the well-written migration candidates can't be migrated.  Here's another good one that should belong on CodeReview:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164179/am-i-suffering-divitis-css-especialist-needed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If a question is older than 60 days, then the option for moderators to migrate a question is disabled.

See this [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

> questions older than 60 days should not be eligible for migration, either by normal user close-votes or by moderators. In extreme cases, we can perhaps provide an alternate means of moving old questions, but under normal circumstances these should be done quickly or not at all.

These migrations can only be done by an employee and they would only be done under certain circumstances. The migrations from MSE to MSO are slightly different due to the split of the two sites and those migrations have all been handled by employees.

Comment: The obvious follow-up question: **why** does this restriction exist?

Answer (score 8):

The only people that can migrate questions older than 60 days are SE employees, and then they only do so in very rare circumstances. Regular users and moderators can't.

The only reason you are seeing these migrations at the moment is because of the Meta Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Exchange split.

Answer (score 8):

Questions that are being migrated from meta.stackexchange.com to meta.stackoverflow.com are being migrated due to the [Meta split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014), on a case by case basis.  Employees have the ability to override the 60 day restriction.