# Migrate all CodeGolf questions now?

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm fairly new to the Stackexchange system, Area51 betas and the multitude of sites, but I incidentally stumbled upon something I think should be discussed:

There are as of now 213 questions [tagged code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) on SO. I was somewhat irritated by that since I have been browsing [codegolf.stackexchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) recently and it never occured to me that such questions had been asked on SO before its creation. But they were and there was obviously some fuss with programmers.SE as well. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73372) from Jeff states that code-golf questions are allowed on SO

> until such time as the Area 51 Code Golf proposal gets traction.

Well I personally think it has and I think I'm backed by the fact that the tag description for code-golf on SO states

> Code Golf is no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow. See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

So: **Shouldn't those 213 questions be migrated now?**

I have searched meta.SO and meta.SE for this but I could only find questions regarding the quality of code-golf on SO and regarding the Programmers vs. SO debate so I dare ask a new one here.

Comment: Questions older than 60 days are never candidates for migration.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can or can't questions be migrated after 60 days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258349/can-or-cant-questions-be-migrated-after-60-days)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

Mass migrations were tried in the past but ended up causing more problems than they solved. It skewed the reputation leagues in favour of people who didn't actually participate on the target set for one thing.

Most (if not all) of those 213 questions will be old, answered questions so there's no benefit to anyone in having them migrated. There's no guarantee that any of those questions actually meet the "on-topic" criteria for code golf.

If these questions aren't useful on Stack Overflow it's far better and simpler just to close here and then let the automatic clean up processes get to work.

Comment: `If these questions aren't useful on Stack Overflow it's far better and simpler just to close here and then let the automatic clean up processes get to work.` These questions used to be on-topic. Aren't they supposed to get historical locks?

Comment: @dorukayhan historical lock is really only for questions with high views and lots of incoming links - in other words valuable content. Something with low views shouldn't be locked and I'd say that code golf questions would have to be *really* good to warrant locking.