# Burninate [code-golf]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490950/looking-for-some-code-golf-literature) come up today, with a really good comment that the [code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag description itself states that code golf questions are [no longer on-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info):

> DO NOT USE - Code Golf is no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow given the existence of [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

This seems like it might be a decent candidate for burnination, [based on #2 of "Does this tag even need to be burninated?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

The only reason I could think for keeping this tag is that there are [older, pre-`codegolf.stackexchange.com` questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304713/code-golf-prime-factors-of-a-number) that were on-topic for the time... although the fact that the tag is *currently* off-topic seems to me to trump that.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would vote for existing questions to be grandfathered in and the tag to stay as is (with note directing users to the new SE site).  Unless all existing questions were migrated.

Comment: @JasonMArcher Yeah, that's what I wondered about. *Some* of the questions are good candidates for migration, but many are not, and a [mass migration request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262490/migrate-all-codegolf-questions-now) was already rejected. Although it'd take some work, migrating only the obvious/actual code golf questions could be possible, and would allow this tag to be removed.

Comment: I suppose there is nothing wrong with cleaning up the questions that don't deserve that tag.  Then maybe we can see if the other questions really need the tag?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The remaining questions are a part of Stack Overflow's history. Or mistagged. Either way, there's no particularly good reason for using this tag on any *new* questions, so like [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) before it this is now blacklisted:

[image: Code Golf is a game that was played on Stack Overflow in its early days but is now considered off-topic.]

Comment: `"there's no particularly good reason for using this tag on any new questions"` I disagree. What if the question is asking for clarification on how a certain snippet of code works, where the code in question is written in a typical code-golf way, which you would never encounter in any non-code-golf setting; yet the actual knowledge involved in answering the question is a perfect fit for Stackoverflow? Point in case: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25634191/765294) of mine, of which you yesterday removed the tag, and as a result made harder to search for.

Comment: A number of the great "historic" code-golf questions have recently been deleted (I noticed because I have answers on several of them, and I can see them because I have 10k rep). In the interest of being able to share the interesting questions and answers with people, I wish that they would be undeleted and locked again.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523323/code-golf-regex-parser (53 votes, 19 stars) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480023/code-golf-lasers (151 votes, 74 stars) both deleted at the same time in September.

Comment: @hobbs were they migrated to the PCG site? I'd like to view them. Otherwise, don't you have the rep necessary to do that?

Comment: @mbomb007 no, they weren't migrated because old questions aren't migrated. No, I can't do anything to them except flag because they were deleted by a mod. And I can only find and flag the ones I remember well enough to find traces of on Google, since deleted questions don't show up in search, even to people who can view them.

Comment: @hobbs That's too bad. :/