# Is it the Question or the Answer That Makes a Great Post?

Tags: discussion

[How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

I see a lot of archives like these in the frequent section from years back with some of the most elaborate answers one could possibly imagine to what is otherwise a question that would probably be shut down, down-voted, and considered off-topic today (this one likely to be considered too broad/opinion-based). The question is blatantly asking people for their personal best solution, and with a question that puts in no effort whatsoever into finding a personal solution.

But it's doing something interesting: it's asking a "competitive" question. It sets up the stage for people to compete to provide the best answer for a very broad question instead of, say, the quickest solution to a very specific problem.

In cases like these, I think broad/opinion-inducing questions are sometimes the perfect "bait" for these types of expert answers. When an expert is involved, the answers "save" what would otherwise be a very lazy question and turn them into some of the most revisited questions on the site that can prevent all kinds of new questions from being asked.

And I want to see more questions like this which "bait" excellent, professional-quality answers to extremely broad (and therefore generally-applicable) questions. They're the kinds we can link to people over and over. It's answers like the top answer there which drew me to this site in the first place.

Sometimes the most specific questions aren't going to be the types that rise to the top, since by being so narrowly-applicable to the author's use case, the answers lack this level of appeal with the rest of the world. But I have seen some of the rarer potential "expert baits" like the one at the top get shut down before anyone could even respond.

So I just wanted to kind of throw this thought out there -- no suggestions or implications, as a point of discussion. There are definitely plenty of "too broad/opinionated" questions which would only spawn vague answers that would be of little use to no one.

But I think there's another class that has often prompted some of the finest answers seen on SO. I think there's an awkward dilemma here where we're not so careful to make this distinction anymore when we hastily downvote or request to close a thread. How would we respond today to the question at the top, presuming it had 0 votes and no answers?

**Duality of Purpose**

A lot of what I see as awkward is this duality which tends to be mutually exclusive where:

1. The site wants to be great for answering questions and helping the person asking the question.
2. The site wants to become a great database/archive for finding past gems. This is the side that drew me, since some of the information I found initially while looking through SO were of a much higher professional caliber than most support-style sites. That quality was very alluring. To me this goes beyond preventing duplicate answers, as some of the posts on this site provide very educational information even to those who weren't seeking to ask the same question.

Trying to encourage people to ask questions that invest the proper effort, provide the necessary details, an MCVE, etc. hits #1. A lot of those guidelines are ideal for "troubleshooting" types of questions, but those types of questions tend to have very little applicability to anyone other than the author, as they force him/her to get exactly to the point and narrow down their problem. Yet they don't often tend to produce a question that could be applicable to thousands of people out there, they don't necessarily encourage #2.

Not sure what to do about this. I just wanted to kind of point out this awkward dilemma. A very "general" question is very dangerously close to "lazy/broad/prone to produce subjective answers", but there's a certain class of them which could contribute to that other aspect of the site, which is to become an archive of some of the finest programming-related answers out there.

Comment: [it would probably be migrated to CG.SE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759/839601)

Comment: That question was asked a month after SO started.  There were very few non-subjective questions and a few handful of thousand users.  Anything seemed possible, nothing was off topic.  It took another year before they figured out what was important to make Q+A work.  And a *lot* of really crappy questions that you can't find back anymore.  Clearly this Q+A needs the boilerplate disclaimer: "past performance is not necessarily indicative of future results".  This can't work when questions are asked at a rate of 1 every 6 seconds.  Unless we find 9000 volunteers each day to not ask a question.

Comment: We are not a forum. We don't have threads. Forums have threads ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Ummm... What do we call these "things" then?

Comment: It's awkward -- but I think the tricky part is that the questions which might be best for posterity might actually sometimes include the laziest ones, like "Do I cast the results of malloc?" "What's the fastest way to check if a point is in a polygon?" -- ones that are arguably very broad and rather lazy. If I shamelessly plug in some of the questions I've posted, they tend to be received reasonably well since I put a lot of effort before I ever pose one, but I'm not sure they will ever be that helpful to other people...

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023245/branchless-k-means-or-other-optimizations. While putting in the effort into the question helped me get exactly the answer I was looking for, that kind of effort makes it so it's probably more "interesting" at best to people than really useful, since it becomes increasingly narrow the more detailed I make it. Meanwhile the laziest one-liner broad question might actually be a whole lot more useful to many.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Questions and Answers

Comment: Maybe Q&A? I had a bit of an awkward dilemma if you look at the title of this "Q&A" to try to come up with a term that describes the two bundled together. I realize "thread" is mostly a BBS/e-mail/forum kind of term, but I think it makes sense in this case -- or at least I don't think it would be the source of much confusion. I was thinking "post" as an alternative but I would typically think that's interpreted as one sub-entry, with "thread" being the aggregate.

Comment: I ended up replacing "thread' with "archive" since I was wrong -- the meaning does get misunderstood easily. I should make it clear that the quality I want to emphasize most on SO is opposite of what I think it is emphasizing now -- I don't want to see it be a technical support site, but a site with a great archive of questions and answers. That's why I raised this kind of question about "generally-applicable question" vs. "good question", since by the way the site defines a "good" one, it may be mutually exclusive with a lot of the general ones.

Comment: The system calls them posts.

Comment: @Laurel Why are you bumping a 6-month-old post, just to change one single word in the title? Please don't make trivial edits in old posts.

Comment: @PetahChristian I was searching and I found this post. I think that it's a good question, but with a bad title. The title is very important to the the post, so I changed it so that in the future someone may want to answer it.