# How has the scope of Stack Overflow changed?

Tags: discussion, scope, locked-posts, historical-lock

We have some locked posts on the site. The reason why these posts are locked is that they "are no longer on-topic but have historical significance". I guess "no longer on-topic" implies that they were once on-topic.

Therefore, it can be deduced that the scope of Stack Overflow (what's on- or off-topic) has changed. But how is it changed? What has been changed? Has the scope become narrower or wider?

Comment: It's both. For example there used to be a "lacks minimal effort" close reason which later was abolished because of misuse. Or wasn't there also a "too localized" close reason which does not exist anymore. So while the narrowing surely outweighed the widening it's kind of both, but effectively more a narrowing. Also there is a stackexchange specialized on tool recommendations.

Comment: somewhat related: [Thought experiment: What would happen if we didn't have close votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286407/839601)

Comment: @Trilarion we really need those back.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The topic of Stack Overflow has narrowed over time as the community has learned what kinds of questions are a good fit for the platform, and what kinds of questions attract spam or other undesirable content. For example, SO used to accept questions asking for book or tool recommendations, but it was easy to observe that those kinds of questions generate mostly noise and not much signal. As a result, a handful of these questions that did have some value were locked so that they wouldn't be deleted as we purged the noise.

Comment: another prominent example is [code golf questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759/839601)

Comment: What is "undesirable content"? Spam, noise, opinions, ...?

Comment: Since the questions have been closed in the way the OP mentioned the sense of community here has been all but destroyed. The users were people, not just robots looking for the next snippet to copy and paste as it seems now.

Comment: If by 'community' you mean begging for beer in your profile, I'm happy to see it go.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, there was some spam introduced by these kinds of questions, but I think the higher volume of noise was in the form of the same questions being asked every day, and generating the same long list of favorites (so, opinions).

Comment: @Jonathan I don't see what one thing has to do with the other.

Comment: @bmargulies, ahah thats actually my point, I haven't bothered updating my profile, I'm 21 now as well. I don't bother browsing the site anymore, there aren't really any interesting questions or discussions. The front page of SO might as well be blank, except for the sidebar as the Hot Network Questions are the same type of interesting questions as there used to be here.

Comment: So, you are on one side of the argument about what these sites are for, and I'm on the other. The hot network questions are a constant reminder of what stackoverflow escaped from, to me.

Comment: I think they should primarily be for asking and answering questions (obviously), I don't have any specific proof, but it seems reasonable to assume people are going to interact more with things that interest them. I can go hunt for questions I can answer for internet points but thats really quite useless to me, or I can be browsing for interesting things and then come across a question I can answer.

Comment: We have tags, so imo any questions that are closed with "no longer on topic but have historical significance" should just be tagged as such and allowed again and then anyone who wants to get rid of that noise can just filter out that tag.

Comment: @Jonathan. This isn't a hangout. There are chat rooms for that. The main site if for questions that have specific and objective answers. Search engines don't aggressively index sites that present more noise than signal.

Comment: @gnat And now we have [a site for those](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) :P

Comment: @cat A lot of the narrowing is due to creation of new stackexchange babies. Taking all stack exchanges together it's not really a narrowing (rather a huge widening over the last years). Maybe the better word would be specialization. StackOverflow specialized on some things it can do really good. The other part is learning what doesn't work in FAQ. Although I would guess that unclear questions were off-topic everywhere right from the start, or weren't they?

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, I remember when SO was bombarded with questions about Aviation, Woodworking and Parenting, too. /s Specialised is definitely a better word, and to answer your question, I think that's correct with the exception of [tag:code-golf] questions on SO. Almost every single one that was asked in the Good Old Days(tm) would be closed on CodeGolf.SE today for being extremely unclear. (They were games amd so people gotta way with it. No such luck on PPCG.)

Comment: I hate the fact that we don't allow questions of the form "is there a library that does X?". I advise people to get round this by asking instead "I want to write some code that does X", which will soon get the response "You don't need to, there's a library that does it".

Comment: @MichaelKay Which makes for a much better question, because then people are forced to write up their full requirements instead of just asking for "any library that does X?" They can also post on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library).

Comment: @MichaelKay unfortunately, questions reworded like that can still run into "Too Broad" in a number of different ways. I'm sure I've voted "Unclear" or "Too Broad" before on questions saying "I want to achieve X" that didn't specify which part of X was causing them trouble. But who knows, if the right library existed then maybe the question could be answerable as-is without going into those details.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to Bills great answer, a lot of questions have become off-topic for Stack Overflow over the years as new, more specialized sister sites emerged. *[Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour)* is a wonderful example; it was once on-topic for Stack Overflow, but now is its own dedicated site.

Similar to that, [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) is now a thing, as well as [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) as well as [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour), [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour). While some questions are still acceptable on both sites, some others are not.

In the early days, Stack Overflow accepted a lot more questions because Stack Overflow still had to learn what questions were a good fit for a Q&A format, and because other specialized sites did not exist.

A good way to learn about how Stack Overflow's meta shifted is by reading high-rated meta posts from various times.

I don't think anyone has ever compiled a comprehensive review detailing the changes over time very precisely.

Comment: *I don't think anyone has ever compiled a comprehensive review detailing the changes over time very precisely.* Only in our minds ;)

Answer (score 20):

> How has the scope of Stack Overflow changed?

In the beginning…

No, I'm not actually going to reminisce about "the good ol' days", because I was actually relatively late to the party (at least as far as account creation is concerned).

Over the years things have changed drastically on Stack Overflow for what was considered "on topic".

When I joined there was a different set of "off-topic" close reasons, and closing duplicates took a lot more votes. These things have changed because we as a community have polished the experience.

Stack Overflow aims to be the best, which means figuring out what kinds of questions generate the most noise, and getting rid of them.

Right now you're using the mother of all scope changes on Stack Overflow.

**Once upon a time there was no Meta**. If you had a question about Stack Overflow, you had to ask on…Stack Overflow. This obviously created a lot of noise because the questions weren't about programming, so they needed to be removed from the system.

So Meta Stack Overflow was created as a home for questions about Stack Overflow, which cleaned things up quite a bit.

Then, as more and more sites were created, and SO became "Stack Exchange", Meta.SO became the "Meta Meta" site when you needed to ask a question about Stack Exchange in general. Meta itself was then spun off into Meta Stack Exchange to again reduce the noise.

> Has the scope become narrower or wider?

These changes happened progressively, and they've consistently made the scope of Stack Overflow narrower.

This is A Good Thing™.

Stack Overflow started by trying to be better than other sites which I won't mention, but without any knowledge about what *exactly* was needed to be "better". Any question that fit the general guidelines of the site was allowed at first. It quickly became apparent that some categories of questions led to poor quality answers.

To separate the wheat from the chaff the scope was narrowed, and then narrowed some more, and then some more.

Comment: *"Once upon a time there was no Meta"* - but we had UserVoice. I just don't know if UserVoice was launched a few days after SO or a few months later.

Comment: "Stack Overflow aims to be the best" Anyone else who doesn't aim to be the best? :)

Comment: @Trilarion Don't laugh, our Inland Revenue(Government Tax Collector) in the UK has a stated aim to achieve 60% accuracy :-)

Comment: @Trilarion, Different companies have different missions. I definitely recommend looking over the mission statements for various big-name brands. There are many that will use phrasing along the lines of "we strive to provide affordable service to as many people as possible". Those sorts of companies usually aren't looking to be the best in their field, because being the best often comes at a cost.

Comment: Stack Overflow *is* the best. Best is generally a moving target.

Comment: @zzzzBov It's not as if StackOverflow is charging questioners or visitors. So their income is rather low and the income of the answerers is even zero. I agree, they are the best in their field, but how did they manage to achieve it, if they have not much more income than the competition?

Comment: @Trilarion, what makes you think their income is "rather low"? Their profits originated from advertising, and later careers was added, which is a paid service. The founders had a strong business plan, and the competition was rather incompetent at the time. Honestly though, the answer to "how did they manage to achieve it" for pretty much any company tends to be "skilled people working hard, and a lot of luck."