# Should we just delete old questions with lots of votes for being in wrong SE site?

Tags: discussion, migration, vote-to-delete, old-questions

If we have old content, which

- is older than the migration time limit
- has decent amount of up-votes and views for the age of the question
- has therefore clearly helped a lot of people
- is clearly off-topic at SO
- **would be on-topic in another SE site**

then **is deletion the only way to deal with this content?**

As I understand, in exceptional cases SE staff could do the migration even for old question. But what if the question doesn't feel that exceptional, it just appears to be something which many people looking for a solution to their problem found valuable enough to up-vote, and would today be valid content for another SE site. For reference only, what prompted me to ask here is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030557/nfs-server-changes-in-etc-exports-file-need-service-restart), which to me seems clear enough question about a specific problem, with enough information to answer it (if you know how NFS servers work), and looking at the votes and views is a common problem.

As discussion, there is also a slight problem with question activity bumping the question to the front page, which is then likely to result in close or deletion process starting for off-topic questions. This sounds good in principle, but useful off-topic questions are more likely to get changes which result in question activity, so useful off-topic questions might be more likely to get deleted, than unuseful questions (which don't get activity). So end result might be useful stuff getting deleted before unuseful one, reducing signal-to-noise ratio. Maybe.

Comment: If we aren't going to maintain it, but there's a site willing to do this for us, I don't see a lose anywhere. The internet gets curated content, the other site gets traffic, we fix the window.

Comment: It would be nice to add a feature to suggest moving a question to a ***.stackexchange site, rather than just having the option to close it as off-topic. The move suggestion could then be reviewed in both the source and the destination sites.

Comment: Upvotes don't bump questions. I'm not sure where these users saw the cquestion, but it hadn't received an upvote for over a month before it started getting delete votes (and it was closed 8 minutes after it was asked).

Comment: @animuson Upvotes don't bump? Ok, I thought they did. Edits do at least, and maybe new answers too? Anyway, I'll edit the wuestion to remove this misconception.

Comment: did you consider [meta-tag:historical-lock], if not - why? As far as I know this was done a while ago to whole bunch of [old code golf questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759/839601)

Comment: @gnat You mean, request historical lock by flagging to community moderator? The thought did not occur to me. Though I'm not sure that is appropriate for the linked question, but then again declined moderator flag is not such a bad thing, so I guess that is a valid solution.

Comment: @gnat why lock it when there's another community willing to keep it?

Comment: @Braiam per my reading, this discussion doesn't assume another site community expressed a will to get the question, merely that it's on-topic over there: "would be on-topic in another SE site"

Comment: @gnat how else you interpret "is on topic here" other that "we are willing to have that topic asked here"?

Comment: @Braiam easy peasy - reader believes it is on-topic over there, nothing else. This doesn't imply neither that other site community agrees nor that they want to get the question migrated to them (if you're interested in examples when other site community complained about SE management migrating old questions like that without asking if these are welcome, check Software Engineering meta)

Comment: @gnat where I'm talking about "migration" as in "move the question keeping the votes and history"? That doesn't apply to my argument. Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056912/792066 vs http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84676/41104. Same question, basically same content, but the latter got critique that the former did not. I'm talking about those questions.

Comment: @Braiam that's what you wrote: "why lock it when there's another community willing to keep it?" Per my reading this assumes moving the question - because the only other alternative to locking is eventual deletion

Comment: @gnat I perhaps was too subtle about it, so let me be blunt: why are the only two options lock or delete? Why isn't lets move it to the site that seems to like that content? Why is SE migration the only way to move such content? There are several alternatives as to how to fix questions so they don't deserve closure, and none of them involve voting or popularity. Because we haven't figured that out is exactly why we are in this mess.

Comment: @Braiam the way you describe about moving sounds the same as it was until Oct 2012 and it was proven to work so bad that [SE team had to abandon it, even for moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/165773). If there is a difference I couldn't see it. As for editing to make it on-topic you are right, that's a legitimate way I forgot to mention - it is only that sometimes this way is blocked by already existing answers or people are not interested to invest their effort into edit

Comment: @gnat we have learned a lot since then. As I said before, there has been cases where migrating content (again, not the post, nor the votes, but the question itself) has proven to at least not cause problems. Again, refer to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84676/41104 <-- *this* is the kind of migration I feel we should do (everything about that question is not the same as the [original one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056912/792066)). Oh, btw, I totally believe there's a problem with the way migration works, not the concept itself but how it's implemented.

Comment: @gnat now that I read the full feature, I agree with Gilles. The problem of migration wasn't the old vs new, nor the votes, the problem with migration is that normally kicks in *too late* and there's no way for the other side to migrate stuff *they want*.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have your answer:

> - is clearly **off-topic at SO**
> - would be **on-topic in another SE site**

We should migrate the content to where it belongs. By migrate I'm not merely including the mechanism that moves questions across sites, but real content migration. Personally, [I've done this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84676/41104) and I know a very successful [free programming books list](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books). So, if you see content where *it doesn't belong* don't feel sad deleting it, as long as it is available and maintained the internet as whole will benefit, and we too.

Comment: While I agree with "we should migrate the content to where it belongs" in principle, I also think that the current migration tools and guidance aren't that great. They're actually pretty crap. This is why migration is so limited. If the migration tools would be better (e.g. review cues on the target site, or some of the other  ideas) then it would probably be a lot less painful to migrate stuff for everyone involved. Unfortunately, the SE team seems to see migrations as intrinsically problematic and hasn't tried to solve the problem yet :-(