# Add a mechanism to migrate old questions in tags that are being burninated

Tags: feature-request, migration

Can there be a mechanism to migrate old, off-topic questions in tags that are "officially" being burninated?

The [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) and [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) tags, for example, have a number of popular (and often otherwise-reasonable) questions that are considered off topic now that we have Software Engineering and Project Management SE sites. There have been proposals to burninate, blacklist, or clean up those tags, and I suspect that one of them will be done eventually. Even if those particular tags aren't burninated, I think that this is still worth doing because there are bound to be other tags like this.

The community consensus is that burnination should always be done in ways that minimize information loss. This measure would help.

A few possible rules:

- The question must have a tag that's subject to an "official" burnination or cleanup effort (i.e. the migration request must be linked to a Meta post that's tagged as [status-planned] as well as [cleanup-request] or [burninate-request]).
- The question must have been closed as off-topic for one of the following reasons: General Computing, Professional Server Administration, or Custom Close reason. (Questions closed as typographical errors, insufficient information to debug, too broad, or unclear are presumably *not* worth migrating).
- The question must have a positive score as well as at least one answer with a positive score. (We could even say, for argument, that they must have a score of +5 or +10). Again, questions with negative scores probably aren't worth preserving.
- **Edit:** It would probably be a good idea to post on potential "target" site's Meta to see if they're OK with being the recipients of the questions.

Comment: Have you asked on Software Engineering and Project Management SE whether they want us to send these questions there?

Comment: @RobertLongson That's a good point. If this proposal goes anywhere, it would be worth posting on their Meta sites to see if they agree. I edited to include that as a point.

Comment: Have you considered the impact of migrating high voting questions or answers on the target sites?  One of the reasons why old migrations from SO do not happen is the traffic volume (and associated voting) could skew the rep distribution on smaller sites

Comment: Patient: _"Doc, it hurts when I migrate old questions with lots of votes!"_ Doctor: _"So don't migrate old questions with lots of votes!"_ **Good** Doctor: _"Hmm, that [seems to be broken, let me fix it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions)."_

Comment: ["The remaining questions are a part of Stack Overflow's history..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759/839601)

Answer (score 0):

While I get that preserving questions is the intention, the issue I'm struggling with is with the premise.

## We're migrating these questions because *we* don't want them here, but they *might* be on topic somewhere else.

Effectively, it's like donating to your local Arc or Goodwill; we're giving someone else our old stuff, and dusting our hands of the matter.

---

There are problems with this approach:

- **The target site may *not* want the question, or (more commonly) it may already be duplicated.**  I have little doubt in my mind that a good, on-topic question on the target site has already been asked, and if we just ask the target site to take *another* one, we've created work for that community to link to the duplicate.  More commonly, it may be that the site just says, "No thank you," and that's the end of it.  We're no better off than if we hadn't bugged them at all, and just deleted it.
- **Only in rare circumstances, Stack Overflow employees can migrate questions older than 60 days...and it should stay that way.**  There hasn't been a problem of *truly* valuable and relevant questions being migrated, even if they're older beforehand.  We only presume that value is lost, but the more I've seen discussions around older questions, the more I tend to believe that value *isn't* lost.  Only when it's *truly* exceptional do we really need that sort of intervention.

Comment: By that logic, though, why allow migration at all (even for recent questions)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  A relatively new question which is asked in the wrong spot isn't the same as a question which has been only resurfaced because of a burnination effort.  Stack Overflow can only migrate to a handful of select spots anyway, if you recall, and the overarching intent there is to give the OP the best opportunity at an answer given their subject matter.  Questions over 60 days old don't realistically have the OP eager to clarify anything with their question, or make edits in the way only they can.

Comment: Honestly, the more I have to deal with it, the more I realize that migration is *completely* broken. Raising a flag and asking mods to decide if/which site a question should be migrated to just doesn't work. I haven't the foggiest clue what is in-scope for Raspberry PI or Internet of Things, and I shouldn't have to decide whether a question is better-suited for Unix/Linux or SU. I'm a *Stack Overflow* moderator, not an All The Things moderator. I don't know other sites. I have a few ideas of how to fix this, but they've been proposed before, and it's too long to describe in a comment anyway