# The [code-golf] tag blacklist notice uses the wrong name for the Code Golf site

Tags: bug, feature-request, tags, tag-blocklist

[code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is currently [blacklisted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759/7742131) meaning that when you try to add it to a question, you get a message saying

> The 'code-golf' tag is not allowed.
>
> Code Golf is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Check out the Stack Exchange site dedicated to [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

However, [2 years ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/heres-your-site-design-preview), Code Golf changed their name to "Code Golf and Coding Challenges".

It's a minor change, but can the blacklist warning be changed to use the proper name of the site?

Comment: How come there are 139 questions with a blacklisted tag? Isn't burnination a preliminary step to blacklisting?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Burnination and blacklisting are two separate things, that often go together. In this case (based off what [Shog says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759/7742131)) code golf is "historically significant", so the tag has stayed on existing questions, just not added to any more

Answer (score -7):

...if you click the link it takes you to the right site, which is the ultimate goal/objective/purpose.

If there were no link, I would absolutely justify a code change.  But because there *is*, I don't see much value at all in updating the blacklist warning.

Clicking the link to get a user to the site that they want to ask their golf question on is the objective.