# How can I transfer a question on Stack Overflow to Project Management?

Tags: discussion, migration, stack-exchange, site-crossover

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658836/how-do-you-apply-scrum-to-the-design-part-of-web-development), which is irrelevant on Stack Overflow but would be a nice fit in the [Project Management SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com).

Can anyone help me out, please, to do that?

Comment: For starters: *Don't flag for mod attention*. The post is too old to be migrated.

Comment: oh no @BhargavRao. I was not aware that there was a time limit on each post. Sad to hear.

Comment: Andy posts older than 60 days cannot be migrated.

Comment: Linked question looks very opinion based to me. Generally unless you actively participate on target site and 100% sure question is ok there I'd not recommend migration. (Based on your reputation on Project Management SE it does not look like you spend significant amount of time on that site - I would not try migrating anything)

Comment: see also [Can or can't questions be migrated after 60 days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258349/can-or-cant-questions-be-migrated-after-60-days)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posts more than 60 days old [cannot be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days), even by moderators. There are [special situations where employees can override this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258349/can-or-cant-questions-be-migrated-after-60-days/258355#258355), but that tends to be pretty rare.

Beyond that, we've been cautioned against migrating questions to sites under beta. I'll quote [Tim Post on this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/can-we-please-add-http-sqa-stackexchange-com-as-a-migration-target/5780#5780):

> With that being said, we don't establish migration paths to a site that is still in its beta period. We don't want to send content from one site to another unless we're certain that the target site is a permanent fixture. There are exceptions to this; moderators *can* migrate relatively new questions to sites not in the current migration path, but this ability should be used sparingly. A question should be of much better than average quality, and all hope of it being on topic for the current site should be exhausted prior to going around the established routes.

Beyond what Tim said above, we've been encouraged to let beta sites develop their own culture by asking and answering new questions, not letting old questions asked on a different site with a different culture influence the new one. There are cases where moderators and members of a beta site have made strong arguments to move a recent question or two over, but usually we reject migration requests to new sites.