# Can we let moderators migrate misplaced meta-questions older than 60 days?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, migration

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984613/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle), which I flagged for migration to Meta SO. It got declined as I didn't realize [even moderators can't migrate after 60 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258349/can-or-cant-questions-be-migrated-after-60-days).

What should even be done about a question in this situation? It's clearly useful, just not on-topic where it is.

I feel like the solution is to allow migrations by moderators from a site to it's meta equivalent at any point.

Migrations to a meta-site avoid the major problems with normal migrations:

- Moderators of the base site will be very familiar with what is on-topic for the meta-site, so there is little chance of trash migrations.
- Vote counts on meta-sites hardly matter (or at least much less than on base sites as there is no reputation involved). This means no worrying about what happens to votes when a question is migrated.

It seems this second issue is in fact what triggered the [60-day rule in the first place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

I honestly don't see any potential issues with migrating the question "as-is" with no changes to vote counts or answers, besides the effort involved in implementing this different migration type (Perhaps there are just not enough cases of >60-day old meta-questions on base sites to justify this change).

That being said, please bring up any issues you see.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258355/4284627), employees can migrate old questions so I used the contact us page to ask them to do so.

Comment: I guess that's the solution if there are barely any of these old "meta on base site" questions. But still feels like high overhead to have to have to go to an employee for a very simple migration.

Comment: @River Indeed, it *is* a ton of effort for very little, if any, gain.  That's why very old questions generally just shouldn't be migrated.  Just vote to close them as off topic, if they're off topic, rather than trying to migrate them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I migrated the question over since it was useful and folks did put a fair amount of time into answering it, would be a shame to lose that. However, this isn't really *that* big of a problem to add complexity to the already semi-fragile migration path stuff.

Right now, someone with developer access can manually move these things, which works as a pretty good exception handler for the ~2 or 3 times each year this comes up. It's not the rep / votes that matter the most, migrations are supposed to enhance the *user's* experience; it's kinda rare that we'd want to send something over when the OP has probably long since forgotten about the question, hence the 60 day rule. This was one of the rarer cases where it was just a matter of moving over information.

If this becomes an increasing problem on higher-traffic sites we can take another look at it, but even today at Stack Overflow's scale it's *extremely* rare to see something that should be on meta posted on the main site and not quickly closed / migrated.

Not a horrible idea, it's just not worth the additional complexity for the very low volume of occurrences that we currently see.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking this might be one of those "effort invested is more than effort saved" kind of issues. Thanks for providing the data to confirm.