# "Custody battle" over a question

Tags: discussion

The question I'm referring to is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376339/body-has-already-been-defined-for-function-main).

It's a rather old question, and for a long time it was left untouched. However, in recent times, it's been deleted repeatedly and that prompted me to want to "settle this".

As you can see it's a heavily downvoted question, which is generally a good indicator of the question's quality.

In this case however, I and those who have voted to un-delete the question we're in agreement that while the question itself was downvoted heavily, the fact that both answers to it have gotten many upvotes (a good portion of which were passive upvotes) shows that it is in fact an easily searchable and actually useful.

My question to you then is, could/should it be undeleted and get some sort of protection to keep it from being re-deleted or should it just stay "dead" ?

Comment: The answer may have lots of upvotes, but they're not terribly good. They don't actually give any advice as to how to fix the problem - just state the obvious. Not much value.

Comment: @Mat How often do you upvote answers you dont find useful?

Comment: @Borgleader: Happens all the time. I doubt you can convince anybody that there's some plague of idiots who don't see the problem with two `main`s.

Comment: @Borgleader: sort of a [bikeshed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange) problem. Same for answers to typo questions like "_you forgot a `;`_",  they get lots of votes, fast (before hopefully getting nuked with the question).

Comment: I just knew this was about 'two mains' before opening it.

Comment: @Borgleader: I'm pretty sure a bunch of those upvotes were for the Highlander reference.

Comment: @Borgleader [Crap answers get upvoted all the time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10585811/508666). And those answers really are not of high quality by any definition. Question is deleted, I suggest to keep it like that and nothing of value is lost (besides the imaginary internet points which I suspect this meta question is actually about)

Comment: @Mat - last time I checked, customary answer quality and correctness was not emphasized on Stack Overflow. For an answer to be considered "good", it just needs to be upvoted. The [sites goals](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) state *"The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find*" (where "best" means upvoted"); and *"Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked"* (but not "correct"). Example: [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/608639), 3800+ votes on the answer and totally wrong.

Comment: @Borgleader - Oh, that kind of question is taboo here. Brace for bombardment into the stone age. You plucked two nerves. First, the one about question and answer quality metrics; and second, the one about archiving content for historical purposes even if its not a good fit for the main site. You might have plucked a third nerve on the moderators: the [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). Some of them get grumpy when they have to intercede due to the meta effect.

Comment: @Borgleader - so one of the underlying problems here seems to be the definition of "enthusiast programmer". As is fairly typical with Stack Overflow, [a policy clarification was requested but was not provided by leadership](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258081/608639). That's a leadership failure. Leadership did not provide clear direction, so the community started bickering among itself over 3 years ago and its still going on today with the little war you are observing (or are part of).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Number of upvotes is never indicative of anything except views. Frankly, both the answers are quite poor (not sure if a non-poor answer is possible), the question is poor, there's nothing worth keeping about this question and as per usual, the number of votes does absolutely nothing to change this equation.

Comment: And is in no way superior to the compiler's documentation.  Which is trivially googled from the error message.

Comment: *"... both the answers are quite poor"* - no, they are both quite good from Stack Overflow quality standards. From [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): *"Good answers are voted up and rise to the top. The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find."*. The problem is in Stack Overflow's definition of good and best answers. Here's a pathological case in point: [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/608639), 3800+ votes on the accepted answer and its totally wrong.

Comment: @Puppy: this is probably very relevant: [Are there any usability studies for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281136/608639). I suspect there's a disconnect between users and those who run the site.

Comment: @jww: Of course there is. Those who run the site have standards, and users just want to post kitty pictures all day.