# Are there any usability studies for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, users, user-interface, user-experience

I was reading [another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263138/608639) and it discussed a paper titled [Sparrows and Owls: Characterisation of Expert Behaviour in StackOverlow](http://yangjiera.github.io/home/works/umap2014_experts.pdf). I found it to be an interesting paper, and I was glad to see an academic treatment of the subject matter.

I've also read comments that speculate on user psychology and their behavior while on Stack Overflow, but I did not see a citation provided. It would be useful (to me and probably some others) to understand the site's users and how they use the site.

Are there any usability studies for Stack Overflow?

---

Related: usability studies often reveal interesting artifacts. As an example in another problem domain, Google is proposing to [indicate HTTP As Non-Secure in User Agents](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2014Dec/), and the members of the W3C's WebAppSec group are discussing (endlessly debating?) Security UX Indicators. But the problem is [most users don't behave like the developers think they behave, and most users don't know how to use Security UX indicator anyway, so its the wrong problem to expend energy and nearly a complete waste of time](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).

For those who are interested, the "correct" strategy in the security engineering context for this particular problem is *Defend, Don't Ask*. Don't expect the user to do the right thing, don't expect the user to provide a reasonable answer to a security dialog, and do the right thing out of the box. Gutmann covers the subject in detail in his book on [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf), and he cites countless Security UX studies.