# Why were my comments, related to the discussion, deleted while other participant's comments are left untouched?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, deleted-comments

I am really wondering, why were my comments deleted, under [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66613100/1553537), where I, and one other member, were discussing some technical points?

Ironically, the counterpart's comments are left untouched and my comments, from that discussion, are deleted, as if *I just agree with those comments* and have nothing to answer.

Well... I think, that is **really** unfair and not even morally correct thing to do.

If we are a community, we have to respect each other and so far, I have been thinking, that this is a place where developers can constructively discuss things, upon disagreement.

**Even** if I had technically wrong points, how come deleting one side's comments in the discussion and leaving other's comments, especially where there is still no mutual agreement achieved, is a right thing to do?

I really feel treated unfairly, and I hope, that this was just some incautious act and nothing more.

I would really want to know - why.

Comment: *this is a place where developers can constructively discuss things*, comments are not meant for extended discussions or any longer needed information. They can basically be deleted at any point. Most probably someone flagged comments on the question as "No longer needed" and a moderator agreed.

Comment: *comments are not meant for extended discussions or any longer needed information* - sure, I myself flag comments when **they make no sense** and/or **they are no longer needed**. However, I have very clearly stated what is different in my case..

Comment: In [my experience on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310219/are-answers-that-contain-only-commented-code-acceptable/310293#comment271126_310293) the opponent has removed his own comments and flags my comments as *obsolete*. While I agree with the existence of such flag *reason*, using this flagging while the **conversation is active** looks strange. Yes, **finally** all comments should be dropped or incorporated into the post. But what is usefulness of the comments if a comment can arbitrary be deleted during an hour?

Comment: It may help to not consider other users your "opponents".

Comment: "*the opponent has removed his own comments and flags my comments as obsolete.*" - this is ok case. If, from the discussion, I remove something for the sake of stepping out from the argument, or clearing out the thread, it may make sense to flag other comments as well, as those other comments might lose their context, hence -> lose their sense; however, again.. my point is clearly described in the original meta question above, and it is *different*. Even if the discussion is not active any longer, it is not fair to remove one side and - leave another.

Comment: @JeanneDark while I haven't used that word (and I understand that you don't refer to me), I think there is nothing wrong with the word "opponent", and it does not necessarily bear the derogatory spirit. We use phrases, like "opponent team", "opponent in the debate" etc. [Opponent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/opponent) is a person who disagrees with something and speaks against it.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri while true there is still no real need to label other people as if there is a competition ongoing. There is a potentially disputable situation. The meta post should be about that situation and not the people involved.

Comment: @Gimby and have I ever pointed, or blamed, or accused anyone *personally* that "this guy/girl had done bad thing to me"? - **never**. The situation is exactly what I'm asking for.. and I, again, repeat, that I think, my question clearly describes what made me come here and ask about the situation.. that's it. But for some **very strange** to me reason, there is a small support for my point.. on the contrary, people happily disagree with my claim (that's my conclusion from downvotes on this particular post) and now the thread goes to somewhere else - "whether to use word *opponent* or not".

Comment: Merriam-Webster dictionary, opponent: one that takes an opposite position (as in a debate, contest, or conflict). Nothing wrong with that in debates, which is the case. There is no need to assume competition, contest or conflict from Tsyvarev's words. It does not help to *not consider other users your "opponents"* when they are.

Comment: @Giorgi With comments on SO/ SE being "second class citizens" to posts, even when used 100% by the book, the best recourse you have here is to flag the other comments as NLN/ "No longer needed". In the future, actual discussions are best held in chat, though short back and forth in comments is *generally* tolerated in practice.

Answer (score 1):

First, I wouldn't automatically assume from looking at the answer that you agree with the comments.

Secondly:

> ...this is a place where developers can constructively discuss things, upon disagreement.

Stack Overflow is still primarily a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum.

Third: if your comments add substantial information beyond what's included in the answer, you really should just edit the answer.

It *does*, however, make sense to leave dissenting comments up for the benefit of future readers. Based on voting, several readers apparently felt that the answer was not correct, and it's useful to future readers to be able to see why they thought that. (These cannot be edited into the answer because it would conflict with the intent of the post).

Comment: "*First, I wouldn't automatically assume from looking at the answer that you agree with the comments.*" - please read the question carefully. Yes, I don't agree, and that's what I say; "*Stack Overflow is still primarily a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum.*" - I know what is Stack Overflow, and I never say, that it's a discussion forum, ***however***, comments can be used for discussing something, when there are some disagreements, and there is nothing wrong with this.. and I have mentioned this in my question as well.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri WRT my first point, it seems like you're assuming that deleting your comments make it look like you agree with the other person's comments, and I simply don't think that it does. I wouldn't look at that and say "see? Even the answerer agrees with the comment!"