# Are there any feature-requests that are not network-wide?

Tags: support, meta

... or asked in a different way: Should there be any feature-request tag here at all? The reason to use it should be quite rare, at least I haven't found much things that are different per site (the only ones I currently know of are "SO has a different design" and "SO has documentation beta")...

Comment: Stack Overflow is *wildly* different from the rest of the network. I could literally show you hundreds of feature requests that are relevant to SO only. In fact, IIRC all those were copied from Meta.SE back when the two Metas were split, so most of the requests you're seeing on Meta.SO are already from that group.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'd really see some of these, please don't show me not hundreds of these feature-requests but the top two and the button two of your list.

Comment: To save time, I'm picking them from my own list of suggestions: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717) (ironically still on Meta.SE), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336128) (true, not *really* specific to SO but currently the one place where it is dearly needed), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258081). Leaving out all the careers/SO Jobs related feature requests like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88786) because they are too obvious (but you can search them using the respective tags).

Comment: Then there's a lot of feature requests that aren't *technically* specific to Stack Overflow because there is no technical reason they could not be implemented on other SE sites, too, but in reality they apply to SO only due to its unique community and size. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5) is an example, also ironically still on Meta.SE.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you for convincing me - I'd leave this duplicate question in as I've searched and read 10 minutes on SE and SO meta and did not found the information in these comments...